# Fathers, sons and relationships

Tags: combinatorics

I found this strange puzzle in an old magazine:

In a group of 32 men, we have the following relationships:
Some of them are “sons” of some others. Every person has 1 “father” at maximum
Every person who has at least 4 “sons” is a “padre de familia”.
“Fathers” eat better food than their “sons”, while each person’s “father” is not considered to be a “father” of this person’s “sons”. 
What is the maximum number of “padre de familia”?

I tried to do a graphical solution but messed up :)

Comment: Where does the food come in...?

Comment: There is likely to be a trick here, but presuming saying "A is the father of B" is equivalent to saying "B is the son of A" and there are no mothers with sons, I would have thought there was an achievable upper bound of $\frac{32}{4}=8$ if these are non-biological titles

Comment: @Henry you are not counting padre Di familia ,, it should be [32/5]=6

Comment: @Henry, that doesn't work, because at least one man can't be anyone's son, or you get a cycle. The maximum is 7 (given by 1 grandfather, his 6 sons, and his 24 grandsons).

Comment: We have a puzzle like that, where one person is both a father and son. Like, A is father of B, who is father of C. Then B is both Father and son.

Comment: @MeesdeVries : I see no rule against cycles, which is why I said "these are non-biological titles".  Is there a law against adopting your great-great-great-great-great-grandfather as your "son"?

Comment: Agree, but I think that this is where the "food" restriction comes in. A father eats better food than his direct sons. So at any given point, a son can't be a father in the reverse order. Only to other men.

Comment: To all who voted it as off-topic (and since I have been in this situation myself): There are times when you post a question/puzzle, for which you don't have absolutely any clue on how to start, and maybe this is why you are asking for help. I would understand your votes if the question was so easy and common and mainstream, if it could be solved using regular maths and so on. Then yes, we would expect for the member to show his work! But here we have a problem that most of us (so far) don't know how to approach. So why don't you leave it open for other members to possibly suggest a solution?